# How to disable dhclient completely in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS without disabling or uninstalling network manager?

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, dhclient

I am so frustrated that there seems to be no solution. I want to use dhcpcd instead of dhclient. How to disable dhclient? I want to use dhcpcd with network manager. Dhclient should not start on boot, it should not automatically started (for example by another process) Please help

Comment: there is no solution there. I want to use dhcpcd instead of dhclient.

Comment: hi it is not `dhcpd` . It is `dhcpcd` , which is an alternative to `dhclient`

Answer (score 0):

In /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf add this line :

> dhcp=dhcpcd

and restart NetworkManager.

Comment: did this, dhclient still starts